# Linking error with pcl_ros_tf

Tags: ros, rosmake, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a package that uses the unstable version of perception_pcl. When I rosmake my package, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcl_ros_tf
```

I found one other post with a similar issue, which was resolved by removing some old files cmake left around in the build dir. I made sure to rosmake with --pre-clean, and am still having this issue. Ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12705/linking-error-with-pcl_ros_tf/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2012-01-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A fix for a [similar problem (#5354)](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5354) was committed today.

If you are using the Debian package, that fix is in the build pipeline and should be available in a few days.

If you want to try it right away, run the current svn version from this URL:

- http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-01-21**:
I was using trunk/perception_pcl_unstable from SVN. Doing a svn up fixed it. Thanks!